# WD My Passport External HD stuck at Formatting

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, formatting

My WD My Passport 1TB stopped working all of a sudden. I just got it 3 months ago. The computer recognizes the hard drive and when I went to Disk Management the file system says RAW. The light just keeps on blinking.
I've been looking for solutions online and I got answers that said that I should try making a new partition. I deleted the old and made a new one and now I'm formatting it and it seems to be stuck.
I think there should be progress shown somewhere but mine just says "Formatting".

I didn't do a quick format by the way. Should I just cancel the format or do I have to wait because I started 5 hours ago and nothing's happened. And the light is not blinking anymore now but the computer still detects the hd. What does that mean?

I don't really care about the data anymore. I just want my hd to work again...

Comment: A full format on a 1TB drive may take a very long time! Possibly up to a good few hours. If you can cancel the format then do that and use a quick format, it shouldn't have any detrimental effect on the disk.

Comment: @BigChris I don't think i can cancel it. When I right-click and then 'cancel format' nothing happens. What should I do?

Comment: Sit it out and wait unfortunately!

Comment: what if i reboot? will that be okay?

Comment: @stringbacon - It shouldn't take an hour to format a 1TB HDD.  At this point it doesn't sound like the HDD even works mechanically.